# Proving a variant of Farkas' Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I am given a variant of Farkas' lemma as,

For any $m\times n$ matrix $A$, vector $b\in\mathbb{R^{m}}$, $k\times n$ matrix $C$, and vector $d\in\mathbb{R^{k}}$, exactly one of the following holds:

i) there is a column vector $x\in\mathbb{R^{n}}$ such that $Ax\leq b$ and $Cx=d$; or

ii) there are row vectors $y\in\mathbb{R^{m}},z\in\mathbb{R^{k}}$ such that $yA+zC=0$ and $yb+zd<0$.

I start by showing at least one is false. So lets assume that both i) and ii) are true,\begin{equation}0=0\cdot x=(yA+zC)x=yAx+zCx\leq yb+zd<0,\end{equation} which is a contradiction.

Now I must show that at least one of i) and ii) is true. I have seen a method in my lecture notes that lets me believe to take $A^{\prime}:=[A\;C\;-C\;I]$ and taking $A^{\prime}x^{\prime}$ for some vector $x^{\prime}$, but this method is used for only one matrix. I don't see how to apply this to two matrices with a separate conclusion for i) and how to combine the conclusions for ii). Is there someone who knows how to apply this method?